# Powering 66 LEDs

Tags: led, current, circuit-design

I am trying to figure out some electrical values for a circuit I am designing.  I am wiring 66 RGB CA LEDs in parallel.  Each color channel takes 20mA (2.2v for Red and 3.2v for Green and Blue).  How do I figure out the total ammout of current I'll need to drive each channel?

[LED Datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/YSL-R596AR3G4B5C-C10.pdf)

Comment: Take a wild guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run all colours at the maximum rated current of 20 mA, that will be 60 mA per RGB LED. for 66 RGB LEDs, you will need 3.96 amp.

If you run at a lower current, for less brightness, or know that all three colours won't be on at the same time, you will require less current.

Comment: So I am guessing that I'll need to use a 2A rated transistor on each channel to isolate my LED driver IC from that much current.  The base needs to be negative and I can compensate for the voltage drop. Is there a transistor you'd recommend for this application?  I would prefer an SMD one.

Comment: @MuscleNerd there are plenty of LED driver ICs with integrated FETs that are rated at 1.5-2.0 Amp

Comment: The closest driver IC's I have found are intended to be used for camera LED flashes.  Sadly it's not suited to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Nch FET will drive 66*20mA =1.32A per colour, so for 100mV drop or less RdsOn=<0.1/1.32 Ohms and Vgs(th)<=1/3 Gate voltage with each LED having a current limiting R.

Red =(5-2.0-0.1)/20mA=145 Ohms per Red and BG R’s = (5-3.1-0.1)/20mA= 90 Ohms

PSU needs to be 5V 5A 2% or better.

Comment: @Misunderstood can’t string in series for LEDs given as CA. .. kma. 1.32A per FET

Comment: Nonsense you can’t wire CA’s in series

Comment: You are confused my answer is clear

Comment: Since 3 drivers are needed my answer defined what was needed for parts and R’s and suggested 5V 5A for headroom on power. But the OP does not understand what is actually needed. So it matters not to me if they yet don’t understand the details but it is necessary to complete the design.

Comment: You only need a transsitor switch and resistor for each colour, . An IC is not necessary for 5V

Comment: Nah I would just tap into a PC or again.. any 5V supply 5A (buy not make)  all this was clearly stated in my answer

Comment: your comments only reflect your own state of mind.